# How do i activate this code with a Button?

Tags: c#

As title says. I want to activate this code with a button in FormsApp, but i really do not how to do it.

```
  public static async Task<List<string>> GetProxiesFromSslProxies()
    {
        try
        {
            string rssContent = await new WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://sslproxies24.blogspot.de/feeds/posts/default");
            XDocument feed = XDocument.Parse(rssContent);
            SyndicationFeed sf = SyndicationFeed.Load(feed.CreateReader());

            List<string> allProxies = new List<string>();
            foreach (SyndicationItem si in sf.Items)
            {
                var cont = (TextSyndicationContent) si.Content;
                var matches = Regex.Matches(cont.Text, @"\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}:[0-9]{2,6}\b");
                allProxies.AddRange(from Match match in matches select match.Value);
            }
            return allProxies.Distinct().ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Add a handler to the button: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onclick(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I am not sure what you mean. My problem is that it will not work if i post it into the button,because wait needs async. and if i do private async void Button_Click i cant get any returns from a variable as far as i know

Comment: 2 options: 1. Either you do not need the return value because the button click can't do anything with it, so remove the return value from the signature, or 2. If this method gets called also from somewhere else and consumes in that case the value (so you have to keep the function as it is), make a new `async void` button handler as a proxy that `await`s the result of the method you posted and throws the result there away before it returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a button handler to your button. Then you invoke your method in the handler. You can attach the handler in the WinForms designer - just double click the button. Or you can add it in the constructor of your form:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
}
```

And the handler:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var results = await GetProxiesFromSslProxies();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private async void Button_Click( ... )
{
    List<string> proxies = await GetProxiesFromSslProxies();
    //do something with 'proxies'.
}
```